# webjob read file locally and in production

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

How can I read a file when using Webjobs?

trying to do this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(VirtualPathProvider.OpenFile("~/content/file/file.txt")))
            {
                template = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

But running locally fail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your description, for locally:

We could use following code to get the WebJob project root path.

```
rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

For Azure:

`D:\home` is shared for us and we could read or write file in this path. More detail about Home directory access please refer to the [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#home-directory-access-dhome). File structure on Azure please refer to another [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure). We also could browse it from Kudu (http://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/) tool.

> As a convenience for our customers, the sandbox implements a dynamic symbolic link in kernel mode which maps d:\home to the customer home directory. This is done to remove the need of the customer to keep referencing their own network share path when accessing the site. No matter where the site runs, or how many sites run on a VM, each can access their home directory using

```
 rootPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot"
```

If there is no environment variable "Home"  we could use the following code to do that.

```
 string path;
 if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")!=null)
 {
     path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot" + @"\testfilename.txt"; 
 }
 else
 {
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + @"\testfilename.txt";
  }
```

Following are the detail test steps:

1.Create a WebJob project and test.text file and folder test in the project

[image]

2.As I use timer trigger in the WebJob so I need to add config.UseTimers() in the program.cs

[image]

3 . Add following codes in the Function.cs file

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([TimerTrigger("00:00:03")] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
        {
            string instance = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID");
            string newMsg = $"WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID：{instance}, timestamp：{DateTime.Now}";
            string path;
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")!=null)
            {
                path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot" + @"\test.txt"; 
            }
            else
            {
                path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + @"\test.txt";
            }
            string template = File.ReadAllText(path);
            log.WriteLine($"NewMsge: {newMsg},file Content:{template}");
            Console.WriteLine($"NewMsge: {newMsg},file Content:{template}");
        }
```

4.Test it in the local machine.

[image]

5.After deploy  to Azure and get the log from Azure WebJob dashboard.

[image]

6.After deploy  to Azure and get the log from Azure WebJob dashboard.

[image]